# The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) on Debian 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debian

I am using Visual Studio Code on Debian 10, but I get some problems on my code. One of them is:

The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried many things and lost much time. Here is my code:

```
using System;

    namespace code
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            }
        }
    }
```

My code is right but the erros are in something related with vscode.

[image of the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfdhj.png)

Comment: Could you please put your code directly into your question, rather than linking an image to it?  It's a lot easier for us to help you that way.  See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: I pasted the code here